# How to add Whatsapp sticker pack without third party app in Android?

Tags: android, bots, android-contentprovider, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

I would like to add/import a sticker pack to Whatsapp without the need to use a third party app on android. Generate a sticker pack file and have it interpreted by whatsapp as if it had been imported from an app. For example a node.js server. I have been searching alternatives but with no luck, and i don't know where else to look.

My final goal is to make a bot that given a list of stickers creates a sticker pack that it will be added to Whatsapp

I was reading the Whatsapp stickers "standard"/sample app and in the [advanced section](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android#advanced-development) everything seems to indicate that you need to create an app to import a pack of stickers to whatsapp, since you need a ContentProvider, which communicates for example an app to create stickers with whatsapp in the Android environment.

However my doubt comes to the curiosity that I see that whatsapp web exists and from there its possible to create stickers (I do not know whether to add third party stickers pack). So if I were to use a library like whatsapp-web.js or a bot like Botsapp I could create a code to create a sticker pack (which is basically a .wastickers zip extension with webp files and a json for the sticker metadata) and somehow simulate a ContentProvider that sends this file so it can be opened in whatsapp and be imported as a sticker pack with its own tab in the stickers section.
In sticker apps the action/button that allows this is called [add to whatsapp](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android#intent)

Answer (score 2):

https://personal-stickers-for-whatsapp.de.uptodown.com/android/download

Try this. Add all webp stickers sorted in folders, max 30, to your mobile.
Install / start the app. It will show you the stickers, create by button klick the sticker group and add it to Whatsapp.